# Is there any utility in Solaris/AIX to package a shell Script?

Tags: unix, solaris, packaging, aix

I have a Bash shell script which takes three input files as an argument. I would like to package them all, so I can place that package on any UNIX machines and run it.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do. You want to 'package' your script, or your script should 'package' files?

Comment: want to package my script.

Comment: What kind of package are you expecting? Solaris uses the SVR4 packaging standard (or IPS starting with Solaris 11) but AIX uses its own BFF one. In any case, what's the point about packaging your utility if it is composed of a single file?

Comment: Command `compress myscript.sh` creates a package called `myscript.sh.Z`

Answer (score 2):

There is an old and ancient technique to include a tar file in a executable well known to the grey haired admins ;)

At first create a script ... put it into a file named script

```
#!/bin/bash
TAR_STARTS=`awk '/^__TARMAN BEGINS__/ { print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0`
NAME_OF_SCRIPT=`pwd`/$0
tail +$TAR_STARTS $NAME_OF_SCRIPT | gunzip -c | tar -xvf -
# Insert commands to execute after untaring here .... with relative 
# pathname (e.g. if there is directory "bin" with a file "executable"
# then you should insert a line bin/executable
exit
__TARMAN BEGINS__
```

No newline after the last __

Of course this script is derived from somewhere in the internet. It's not mine. I just cannot remember where for proper kudos.

Then create your tarfile and put it at the end of the file. This is the reason why it's nescessary that there is no newline after the __

```
$ cat script test.tar.gz > selfexploding.sh
```

Now you can just try it

```
$ bash ./selfexploding.sh
tar: blocksize = 9
x testtar, 0 bytes, 0 tape blocks
x testtar/test2, 1024 bytes, 2 tape blocks
x testtar/test1, 1024 bytes, 2 tape blocks
```

You could of course put the name of a script before the exit, that you create by unpack ... of course path must be relative to the pwd of the execution. Don't know if this works with AIX. At least with Solaris 11.3 it works. But as it only uses standard command. It should work everywhere. Besides of this you could of course create native packages for Solaris and AIX.